# cannot load content with jquery mvc 4

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to load partial page contents with jquery.load() method it is loading content but not loading styles. I have searched internet but couldn't found any solution. I'm sharing what i have done so far.

JQUERY:

```
$(function () {
    var site = site || {};
    site.baseUrl = site.baseUrl || "";

    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $(".partialContents").each(function (index, item) {
            var url = site.baseUrl + $(item).data("url");
            if (url && url.length > 0) {

                $(item).load(url, function (response, status, xhr) {
                    if (status == "error") {
                        alert(xhr.status);
                    }
                    return false;
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

View:

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-carousel5">
  <span class="partialContents" data-url="@Url.Action("LoadNew","Home")"></span>
</div>
```

Controller Action:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> LoadNew()
{
    var viewModel = new CategoryViewModel();
    viewModel.Products = await db.Products.Include(c => c.Reviews).Include(c => c.CategoryContents).Include(c => c.Affiliates).ToListAsync();
    return PartialView("_NewProducts", viewModel);
}
```

Comment: Are the styles references in the page you're trying to load or are they in a layout? Are they relative or absolute?

Comment: @user3558931 they are relative and in main layout file

Comment: My guess is that the reason is because the stylesheet paths are relative ... you could confirm by using dev tools. They should at the least be based on the web root for them to work. Example `css/styles.css` won't work but `/css/styles.css` will work.

Comment: @user3558931 my links are like this "/css/styles.css" but not working it is not displaying any content

Comment: Can you use some dev tool to see if there's any attempt to load the styles, and if so, what the paths are?

Comment: @user3558931 yes i have monitored the calls, the paths are being sent correctly. Moreover it is working perfect if i not execute loop. i think there is a problem with model binding, what u say?

Comment: Not quite sure what the cause could be if the stylesheet paths being requested are correct. Wish I could be of further help :(

Comment: @user3558931 actually i want to load partial views using ajax, is there any other or perfect way of doing this?

Comment: it might be, that your css selectors and generated html don't fit each other. Make sure that you haven't missed any container/class which you reference in css, i.e. try to load the whole page mock like you expected it to be after $.load()

Comment: @Dima thanks for the comment, i have tested everything, every sent request is correct even though if i add any tag inside partial view content it will render correctly, but nothing other than that is working, like razor helpers method are not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned in comments that you have referenced css in Layout, you have to return View instead of PartialView.
So,

```
public async Task<ActionResult> LoadNew()
{
    var viewModel = new CategoryViewModel();
    viewModel.Products = await db.Products.Include(c => c.Reviews).Include(c => c.CategoryContents).Include(c => c.Affiliates).ToListAsync();
    return View("_NewProducts", viewModel);
}
```

should do the work.